# Core Data Concurrency on iOS 9

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

If I create a `NSManagedObjectContext` on the main thread with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` must I use `performBlock()` method for all the `save` and `performFetch` methods. IE is it possible to do the following:

```
do {
    managedObjectContext.save()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

or should I always do this:

```
managedObjectContext.performBlock({
    do {
        managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
})
```

If I understand the documentation correctly I always have to use `performBlock()` or `performBlockAndWait()` but in the template code from XCode 7 they are not using blocks. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already on the main thread and have a `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` context, you do **not** need to use `performBlock`.